# UITableViewCell not equal to null

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I'm having trouble with the following code below, which basically is instantiating an extend uitableviewcell from a storyboard. The problem I'm having is that it seems leftMenuCell is *never* equal to null, and thus never enters the initiating block. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LeftMenuCell";
      MenuCell *leftMenuCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

      if(leftMenuCell == nil) {
          NSLog(@"creating a new cell");
          leftMenuCell = [[MenuCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      } ....
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, that's just the way table views work when you make the cell in the storyboard. The method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:, always returns a valid cell when that cell is in a table view in a storyboard. It seems that many programmers haven't figured this out, and still include the if cell==nil clause. This is from the docs:

"If the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method asks for a cell that’s defined in a storyboard, the method always returns a valid cell. If there is not a recycled cell waiting to be reused, the method creates a new one using the information in the storyboard itself. This eliminates the need to check the return value for nil and create a cell manually"

Comment: the problem I'm encountering right now is that I want to initialize some background colors within the extended UITableviewcell (MenuCell) itself, but if alloc is always skipped, then it's left with its default white background

Comment: @Allen, you should implement tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:, and set your colors there.

Comment: how would I access the properties of my extended cell through tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:? (sorry for the noob question)

Comment: I changed the method to this in my call: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(MenuCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. would this be the correct way to use the extended version?

Comment: @Allen, I tried that on one of my projects, and it didn't work. Even if I changed the type of the cell to my custom class, I got a crash. So, I think you'll have to do the color change in cellForRowAtIndexPath, if you're changing the color of a subview.