# Prevent UITableViewCells from repeating content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following code which has 2 sections. I want the first section, which has 3 cells, to have text, and the second section to have no text. The problem is after the 6th or so cell in section 2, the cells repeat the text from section 1.

So my cells look like: Section 1 - Profile, Contacts, Settings; Section 2 - Blank Blank, Blank, Blank, Blank, Profile, Contacts, Settings.

What am I doing wrong?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section == 0) return 3;
    else return 9;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LeftMenuCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Profile";
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Contacts";
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Settings";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    } else {
         //nothing should appear in these cells
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Table view cells are *reused* when you scroll, i.e. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`
can return a cell that was previously used to display a different row.

Therefore you have to set the contents
explicitly, even in the else-case:

```
} else {
    //nothing should appear in these cells
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because of cell reuse. Set `cell.textLabel.text = @"";` in condition where it is not required to show text.

```
if(indexPath.section == 0) {
    //Your code

    // .... 

} else {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this When u Allocs cell

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LeftMenuCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: That might not be necessary, e.g. if the cell is defined as "prototype cell" in the storyboard file. In that case, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` never returns `nil`. See for example the previous question of the OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875759/uitableviewcell-not-equal-to-null.

Answer (score 0):

Cell being reused. see this **dequeueReusableCell**.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

This is happen beacuse Tableview Cell is reused that's so you need to add this  `cell.textLabel.text = @"";` in your else condition. that means second section.